# C# time bool always returning false

Tags: c#

I have a bool that tells me if the current time is in between two other times it will go dark at 8 (20:00) in the evening and light at 7 in the morning.. I am not sure if I should be doing 7 or 07 I have tried booth but still getting false?

Can anyone tell me why this is always returning false? Not much else to say really just that it's always returning false when it is currently in between the two times currently.. GTM Timezone London, Thanks!

```
public static bool NightTime
{
    get
    {
        TimeSpan span = LastMoodlightUpdate - DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(20, 0, 0); //Dark at 20:00
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(07, 0, 0); //Light at 07:00
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
        return ((now > start) && (now < end));
    }
}
```

Comment: How can something be larger than 20 and smaller than 7 at the same time?

Comment: In between them booth.. 8 in the evening and 7 in the morning.. It is pretty easy for that to happen

Comment: You're comparing TimeSpans rather than Dates.  That is peculiar.

Comment: Yeah `TimeSpan`s are for amounts of times.  Not specific times.  Use `DateTime`

Comment: I want it to tell me if it's dark, if it's in between 8 in the evening or 7 in the morning.. That means if its 9,10,11,12,1am,2,3,4,5... you get the flow guys.

Comment: Yes, but the time cannot be both larger than 20 and smaller than 7 *on the same date*.

Comment: We understand perfectly what the problem is but timespan comparison is still a simple numeric comparison. Nothing can be both larger than 20 and smaller than 7 at the same time. You want `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: Interesting username...

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is that comparing two `TimeSpan` values is a simple numeric comparison.

As such, no time can both be larger than 20:00 and smaller than 07:00 in terms of values. We humans can deal with such incongruities, but the computer can't.

You need to consider what you want here:

```
|---------|..................................|-----------|
00        07                                 20          24
```

You want the times in dashes, basically you should use `||` instead of `&&`:

```
return (now > start) || (now < end);
```

Since the time of day cannot be negative, nor can it reach 24:00 or higher, this will give you what you want.

Comment: This makes the busted code work (and earns my upvote), but conceptually it would still be better to use types for their intended purpose.  TimeSpan is just the wrong struct for the job.

Comment: There is no right type built into the .NET framework to handle time. Considering that `TimeOfDay` property returns a `TimeSpan` I say he did everything right. We could all wish there was separate `Date` and `Time` types in the framework, but there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the purpose of all your code.  Isn't it as simple as this?

```
public static bool NightTime
{
    get
    {
        var hour = System.DateTime.Now.Hour;
        return (hour <=7 || hour >= 20);
    }
}
```